# R Shiny: Pin text output box to the bottom of screen

Tags: r, shiny

I am tryin to create a text output box that displays flashing text and fits the criteria below.

1. It will flash and font color will also change when it flashes
2. The box is like a toolbar (like the chatbox on facebook) that is always at the bottom of the screen (pin at bottom full width) such that I do not have to scroll down the page to check out the output of the text output.

What is the best structure for this and how do I do that ?

```
 ui = basicPage(
      # Want below to be a horizontal bar that is pin to bottom of screen at all times
      # 3 textoutput box displayed horizontally, 
      # (not sure how to pin it to bottom and make it flash)
      verbatimTextOutput("default1"),
      verbatimTextOutput("default2"),
      verbatimTextOutput("default3"),

    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$default1 <- renderText({ "Displayed Text 1" })
      output$default2 <- renderText({ "Displayed Text 2 flash green" })
      output$default3 <- renderText({ "Displayed Text 3 flash red" })
    }
```

Comment: Hi JEFF, if you create a minimum reproducible Shiny app that we can cut and paste into our session, with the target UI and what you have attempted, it will be a lot easier for us to produce some recommendation. Thanks :)

Comment: I created a toy example but since I do not know how to pin it to bottom, I am not sure what's the best way to exemplify this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want, but here is an app showing a flash message. It uses the JavaScript library **Bootstrap Flash Alert**.

You have to download the file **bootstrap-flash-alert.js** [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lvitals/bootstrap-flash-alert/master/dist/bootstrap-flash-alert.js), and put it in the **www** subfolder of the app.

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
function flashFunction(opts){
  $.alert(
    opts.message, 
    {
      title: opts.title || null,
      type: opts.type || 'info',
      icon: opts.icon || false,
      withTime: opts.withTime || false,
      autoClose: opts.autoClose === false ? false : true,
      closeTime: opts.closeTime || 5000,
      animation: opts.animation || true,
      animShow: 'fadeIn',
      animHide: 'fadeOut',
      position: ['bottom-right', [0, 0.01]]
    }
  );
}
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(){
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('flash', flashFunction);
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "bootstrap-flash-alert.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  actionButton("btn", "Show flash message")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input[["btn"]], {
    flashMessage <- list(
      message = "Hello! How are you?",
      title = "NOTIFICATION",
      icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart",
      withTime = TRUE
    )
    session$sendCustomMessage("flash", flashMessage)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]